# XPath и ToList в C# Selenium

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

Есть такая команда:

```
List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'blogprice')]")).ToList();
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка CS1061 'IWebElement" не содержит определения для "ToList" и не удалось найти метод расширения "ToList", принимающий тип "IWebElement" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Хотя вверху документа есть: `using System.Linq;`

Пример брался [отсюда](http://software-testing.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/21522-rabota-s-findelements/), но есть подозрение, что команда `ToList` не работает с XPath. Подскажите, как исправить.

#### UPDATE

Там `Links` это часть имени, но почему то появился пробел: полный код выглядит так:

```
List<IWebElement> linksToClick = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'blogprice')]")).ToList();

int linkCount = linksToClick.Count;
for (int i = 0; i <= linkCount - 1; i++)
{

    linksToClick[i].Clear();
    linksToClick[i].SendKeys(text);
    linksToClick = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'blogprice')]")).ToList();
}
```

но к сожалению замена на `Find.Elements` не помогает

Answer (score 2):

Вы путаете `FindElement` и `FindElements`. Первый метод ищет один элемент, второй — все. Ну и вызов `ToList`, скорее всего, избыточен, потому что метод `FindElements` уже возвращает коллекцию в готовом для использования виде.

Comment: но Tolist нужен, так как дальше считаеться количество елементов списка, без него метод к сожалению не работает выдает другую ошибку 
Ошибка CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>".

Comment: @Николай1112 Замените тип переменной на `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`, как вам советует компилятор. Или просто на `var`. У этой коллекции есть свойство `Count`, уверяю вас.

Answer (score 0):

Измени код
`List<IWebElement> linksToClick`
на
`IList<IWebElement> linksToClick`

Answer (score -1):

Перенёс дополнение в тело вопроса. Дополнения к вопросу должны быть в самом вопросе, а не в ответах.